# XML output error - PHP

Tags: php, xml

I want to create an xml file(linkler.xml) in a php file(like task.php) and read/write xml on this php file for an android app.

But I am getting error:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/loumJ.png

Also in xml file error:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWSwD.png

How can i correct this ? Thanks

```
<?php header('Content-type: text/xml'); 
        if(isset($_POST['url'])) { 
           include('curl.php'); 
           include('youtube.php'); 
           $tube = new youtube(); 
           $links = $tube->get($_POST['url']); 
           if($links) { 
              $dosya_adi = "linkler.xml"; 
              $dosya = fopen ($dosya_adi , 'w') or die ("Dosya yok");
              $xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" charset=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
              $xml.='<vidlinks>'; 
              $xml.='<tur>'.$links[0][ext].'</tur>'; 
              $xml.='<link>'.$links[0][url].'</link>'; 
              $xml.='<kalite>'.$links[0][type].'</kalite>'; 
              $xml.='</vidlinks>';
              fputs ( $dosya ,$xml ) ; 
              fclose ($dosya);  
              echo file_get_contents("http://tizentr.net/ara/linkler.xml");
        ?>
        <?php } else {
           echo $tube->error;
        } 
     }
        ?>
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you would post the actual XML source that is causing the error

Comment: We need to see the generated output. not the source.

Comment: Hi, the xml source : http://pastebin.com/UNQZL248

Comment: Why did you close PHP only to immediately reopen it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to conclude all code in:

```
<?php
ob_start(); 
<--code here--> 
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $output;
header('Content-type: text/xml');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There should not be charset word in XML declaration, but encoding word. So you should use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

in your formed XML.

Also you can look in XML guide http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml

This should fix your XML error; and regarding first error check if you have some output in curl.php and youtube.php files, if yes, remove it.

Comment: So your XML source http://tizentr.net/ara/linkler.xml is ok now; does the first error remain?

Comment: Yes it is ok for now. I will use str_replace function for special characters. Thanks lanka.

Comment: If you still getting Extra content error try to remove php tags in lines  `?>
        <?php } else {`

Comment: I removed this lines but still ""error on line 1 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document"".. Can you help me ? Thank you.

Comment: Your XML file http://tizentr.net/ara/linkler.xml is correct. So the error somewhere in PHP file. Please check that no whitespace is printed after `echo file_get_contents()` command. Also remove all whitespaces after ?> in php file.

Comment: Thank you @lanka, i removed whitespaces and the problem is almost solved but this page is blank :  http://www.tizentr.net/ara/index.php

Comment: You can try to a) restart your server; b) check rights on your folder (should be 755); c) try this code `echo file_get_contents("linkler.xml");` (without http). This error can be caused by anything really, if you google it, you'll see the variety of causes and answers.

Comment: Thanks lanka.. You are a lifesaver. I will try these but also i am searching.. Thank you.